# Find the force on a hinged rod in equilibrium

Tags: vectors

Could anyone help me out with the following please?

A uniform rod AB of weight 20N is hinged to a fixed point **A**. A force acts at **B** holding the rod in equilibrium at 30$^{\circ}$ to the vertical through **A**. Find the magnitude of this force if it is perpendicular to **AB**.

I appreciate that as we have three non-parallel forces in equilibrium then we know that their lines of action must be  concurrent. I can use this fact to solve the similar question where the force **F** acts horizontally but am having difficulty with the perpendicular-to-**AB** case.

I call the unknown force **F** and the reaction at the hinge **R**. I label the angle which **R** makes with the vertical through point **A** as $\theta$.

**Resolving parallel to AB** I get:

$R\:cos(30 - \theta)= 20\:cos\:30$

**Resolving perpendicular to AB** I get:

$R\:cos(60+\theta) + F = 20\:sin\:30$

If these are correct then finding $\theta$ would allow me to find F. How to find $\theta$ from the geometry of the diagram I'm not sure.

(I tried labeling the point of intersection of the three forces **C** and the point below **A** and level with **B** I called **D** and the point below **A** and level with **C** I called **E** and so I got $tan\:\theta=\frac{EC}{AE}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}DB}{AE}$ and $tan\:30=\frac{DB}{AD}$ but I haven't gotten anywhere useful yet)

Thanks so much for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: You need to write down Newton's law for linear forces and for torques and simultaneously solve the three equations for the variables needed

Comment: Adding the tag 'physics' may also bring the attention of more people capable of help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...It's easier if you consider the reaction force split into two mutually perpendicular components $X$ and $Y$ horizontally and vertically. Let $a$ be the length of the rod.

Taking moments at $A$ you have $$F\cdot 2a=20a\cos 60\implies F=5$$

Now resolve horizontally and vertically to find $X$ and $Y$, and the magnitude of the reaction force is $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$.

Can you finish this?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. They enabled me to see how to solve the question.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please upvote and/or accept to close the question if this is what you were looking for :)